# Problems with absoft fortran in mac

Tags: macos, fortran

I used to work with Intel Visual Fortran and my code runs smoothly there. However I bought Absoft Fotran Compiler and I am getting many errors...

This is a sample program where I get errors

```
FUNCTION norm_inv(x)
    USE nrtype
    USE tauchen
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP), INTENT(IN) :: x
    REAL(DP) :: norm_inv,zbrent,x1,x2,tol
    tol=1.0E-6
    x1=-10.0
    x2=10.0
    norm_inv=zbrent(fni,x1,x2,tol)
    CONTAINS
    FUNCTION fni(x0)
        USE nrtype
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL(DP), INTENT(IN) :: x0
        REAL(DP) :: fni,norm_cdf
        fni=norm_cdf(x0)-x
    END FUNCTION fni                
END FUNCTION norm_inv
```

And the Absoft compiler tells me

> Message Number: 379
>
> > A procedure name is used as an actual argument to a function or
> >     subroutine call, but the procedure name has not been given the
> >     EXTERNAL attribute, is not a module procedure, or is not specified in
> >     an interface  block.  NOTE:  Giving the EXTERNAL attribute to the name
> >     of the SUBROUTINE being compiled is an extension to the standard.

When I declare it external it tells me

> Message Number: 552 The compiler detected a conflict in declarations
>   for this object.   Because the object has the given attribute, it must
>   not be declared to be the new item.

Comment: Oops, I missed: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9982657/3157076.

Comment: A comment about francescalus's answer: while Intel Fortran's support for Fortran 2003 and Fortran 2008 is rather decent, the same can't be said of Absoft Fortran, as of the current version. See the latest issue of Fortran Forum, or in FortranWiki: *[Fortran 2003 status](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status)* and *[Fortran 2008 status](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status)*

Answer (score 1):

`fni` is an internal procedure of the function `norm_inv` (where the call to `zbrent` is made).  Passing an internal procedure as an actual argument is a feature new to Fortran 2008.  Crucially, this is a feature [implemented](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2647342.2647345) in the Intel compiler, but not the Absoft.

To make the code more "portable" working around things to make `fni` not internal would work.  Merely adding the `external` attribute to `fni` would not be sufficient, and would indeed be incorrect.