# How to pass a function with multiple arguments to a subroutine that expects a function with only one argument?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a subroutine (minimal example)

```
subroutine treatfunction(f,input,output)
   external, real::f
   real, intent(in):: input
   real, intent(out):: output

   output = f(input) + f(1.0)  ! i.e. f has only one argument
end subroutine
```

and a function with two arguments

```
real function fun(x,a)
   real,intent(in)::x,a
```

Now for a given `a` fixed at runtime, I want to pass `fun` to `treatfunction`. So ideally, I would want to call something like

```
call treatfunction(fun(:,a=a0), input=myinput, output=myoutput)
```

What is the most elegant way of doing this with the Fortran2003 features `gfortran-5` supports?

Of course, I could insert an optional dummy argument `a` in `treatfunction` and call `f` either with `f(x)` or `f(x,a)` depending on `present(a)` in the subroutine's body. But changing the subroutine is not elegant.

Comment: You could do this with a wrapper function with one argument which then calls further on.  Such as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/9982657.

Comment: Yeas, I also recall thar was something similar in the past but it is quite difficult to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Fortran 2008 you can pass internal functions as arguments and gfortran supports it.

```
 subroutine calling()

   a0 = ...
   call treatfunction(wrapper, input=myinput, output=myoutput)
 contains
   real function wrapper(x)
     real, intent(in) :: x
     wrapper = fun(x,a0)
   end function
 end subroutine
```

BTW, I would stay away from `external` it is evil, use interface blocks.