# Implement an ODE integrator that can take a general f(x,t) as input in fortran

Tags: interface, fortran, numeric, ode

I want to solve ODEs of the type

[image]

in modern fortran. I want to write the integrator (for example 4th-order Runge-Kutta) to be quite general, such that the same integrator can be used for different right-hand sides of the equation, including at least these different cases:

- f(x, t) is a function, where both x and the return value are scalars
- f(x, t) is a function, where both x and the return value are arrays (of the same shape)
- f(x, t) is a type-bound procedure (or similar), where the purpose of the derived type is to interpolate some underlying data to the position and time given by (x, t)

Based on an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644810/fortran-passing-a-member-procedure-to-an-external-function) I have implemented the code included below, which seems to work as expected.

My problem is that I would like to keep `rk4(x, t, h, f)` general, such that `x` in `f(x,t)` can be an assumed-shape array (or even a scalar, ideally), but at the same time I would like to be able to specify that `x` has for example `dimension(2)` when I actually implement a function to interpolate some 2D data. However, if I try to modify the function `evaluate` in the example below such that `x` has `dimension(2)`, then I get an error complaining about interface mismatch when I try to compile. Is there a way around this problem?

```
module interpolator_module
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: WP = kind(1.0D0)

    interface
        ! This is the general form of the right-hand side of an ODE
        function rhs(x, t) result( val )
            import :: WP
            real(WP), dimension(:),      intent(in) :: x
            real(WP),                    intent(in) :: t
            real(WP), dimension(size(x))            :: val
        end function
    end interface

    type interpolator_type
        ! This type would in practice store arrays,
        ! of discrete data to be interpolated.
        real(WP) :: stored_data
        procedure(rhs), nopass, pointer :: eval
    contains
        procedure :: init
    endtype

    class(interpolator_type), pointer :: interpolator

contains

    subroutine init( this, stored_data )
        implicit none
        class(interpolator_type), target :: this
        real(WP) :: stored_data
        this % stored_data = stored_data
        this % eval => evaluate
        interpolator => this
    end subroutine

    function evaluate(x, t) result( val )
        implicit none
        real(WP), dimension(:),      intent(in) :: x
        real(WP),                    intent(in) :: t
        real(WP), dimension(size(x))            :: val
        ! This is where interpolation would happen
        val = interpolator % stored_data * x
    end function
end module


program main
    use interpolator_module, only : interpolator_type
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: WP = kind(1.0D0)
    type(interpolator_type) :: interp
    real(WP), dimension(2) :: x
    real(WP) :: t, h

    ! initialise interpolator with some data
    call interp % init(-0.1_WP)

    x = (/ 2.0_WP, 1.0_WP /)
    t = 0.0_WP
    h = 1.0_WP

    ! Example of calling rk1 with the "type-bound procedure"
    ! which evaluates an interpolator
    call rk4(x, t, h, interp % eval )
    print *, x

    ! Example of calling rk1 with analytical function
    call rk4(X, t, h, f )
    print *, x

    contains

    subroutine rk4(x, t, h, f)
        ! Makes one step with 4th-order Runge-Kutta.
        ! Calculates next position using timestep h.
        implicit none
        real(WP), intent(inout), dimension(:)   :: x
        real(WP), intent(inout)                 :: t
        real(WP), intent(in)                    :: h
        interface
            function f(x, t) result(val)
                import WP
                real(WP), dimension(:),      intent(in) :: x
                real(WP),                    intent(in) :: t
                real(WP), dimension(size(x))            :: val
            end function
        end interface
        ! Local variables
        real(WP), dimension(size(x))            :: k1, k2, k3, k4

        ! Evaluations of f(x, t)
        k1 = f(x,          t)
        k2 = f(x + k1*h/2, t + h/2)
        k3 = f(x + k2*h/2, t + h/2)
        k4 = f(x + k3,     t + h)

        ! Next position
        x  = x + h*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
        t  = t + h
    end subroutine

    pure function f(x, t) result(val)
        implicit none
        real(WP), dimension(:),      intent(in) :: x
        real(WP),                    intent(in) :: t
        real(WP), dimension(size(x))            :: val
        val = -0.1_WP*x
    end function
end program
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed shape arrays are not compatible with explicit shape arrays (like `dimension(2)`). The calling convention under the hood often uses a completely different mechanism that just would not work. If the compiler let you do it, it would crash the program.

You do not have much choice, because if you use assumed size arrays (`dimension(*)`) you do not have access to the size of the array and you would have to pass it separately. You could store it in the `interpolator` structure but it would still not be ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In the example I gave, which compiles without errors, the function ```evaluate``` takes an assumed-shape array, ```x```, as an argument, and I still have access to the size of ```x``` inside the function, without passing it separately. And in the example, I'm able to pass an explicit-shape array to the functions I have defined with assumed-shape arrays.

Comment: @Tor first be concerned about the first paragraph, the second paragraph is hypothetical about an assumed *size* alternative.

Comment: @Tor The calling code knows from the interface that the function it calls is assumed shape (`dimension(:)`). That is the purpose of the interface. If you try to make the code, using some trick, to call a function that is not actually `dimension(:)`, but `dimension(2)`, the code will still try to call it as `dimension(:)` and it will crash.